# How to fix 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)' error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Every time someone writes an error appears. I hope I didn't make a usual mistake

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands( message )

    with open('C:\\Ультилиты\\ProgramBotDiscord\\lvl.json', 'r' ) as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        
    async def update_data(users, user):
        if not user in users:
            users[user] = {}
            users[user]['exp'] = 0
            users[user]['lvl'] = 1
    await update_data(users, message.author.id)

    with open('C:\\Ультилиты\\ProgramBotDiscord\\lvl.json', 'w' ) as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

Cmd:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "501.py", line 319, in on_message
    users = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Programs\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Programs\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Programs\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Programs\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What does your JSON file contain…?

Comment: nothing @deceze
[images](https://sun9-60.userapi.com/1oy8iuMAMnMbNvpwgh54o4-SKxEOH32ueA2_qQ/XDaayHtgK-c.jpg)

Comment: @MOnsterHak then what do you think JSON could load in ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

There would be your problem, for this to work you need data in your json file. If you want you can have a system such as using the try: and except: to try to receive data and if failed, print out a message or something.